# Getting the Bean name is ambiguous in Managed Bean class org.apache.myfaces.push.cdi.PushContextFactoryBean

Tags: jsf, cdi, myfaces

Hi friends I getting the below error updating enterprise application project from wildfly 18 to wildfly 24, I am using myfaces-2.3.1 version and primeface11.x jar.

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "nss.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."nss.ear".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name oam_PUSH_CONTEXT_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class org.apache.myfaces.push.cdi.PushContextFactoryBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named], Managed Bean [class org.apache.myfaces.push.cdi.PushContextFactoryBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named]]"}}

Please let me know.